# How to list all files via javascript from google drive? API gives some code but not helpful?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, google-drive-api

I am referring to google drive API .
I am able to successfully upload files to google drive but unable to fetch them using javascript.

Comment: Have you tried  files.get or files.list()?  Please refer to these links:    https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list  ,https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get .

Comment: No that didn't workout. Can you post a example of working javascript code. Thanks in advance.